# AngularJS + GAE not updating HTML

Tags: html, angularjs, google-app-engine

**EDIT: Turns out the version being served was outdated - updating the version in `app.yaml` doesn't actually update the served version.**

As the title says, I'm trying to upload changes to an AngularJS app to Google App Engine (Python, if it matters).

The referenced HTML files for each view however will not update and I'm not sure why.

Here's the `app.yaml`:

```
- url: /site/(.*\.(js|css|png|ico|txt))$
  static_files: site/dist/\1
  upload: site/dist/.*\.(js|css|png|ico|txt)$
  login: required
  secure: always

- url: /site/(.*\.html)$
  static_files: site/dist/\1
  upload: site/dist/.*\.html$
  login: required
  secure: always
  expiration: '30s'

- url: /site/.*
  static_files: site/dist/index.html
  upload: site/dist/index.html
  login: required
  secure: always
```

And a couple of examples of HTML referenced in `app.js`:

```
    // Routes
    $routeProvider
        .when('/users', {
            templateUrl: 'users/users.html',
            controller: 'UserCtrl',
            activeTab: 'users',
            reloadOnSearch: false
        })
        .when('/users/profile/:userId', {
            templateUrl: 'users/profile.html',
            controller: 'UserProfileCtrl',
            activeTab: 'users'
        })
        .when('/users/new', {
            templateUrl: 'users/create.html',
            controller: 'UserCreateCtrl',
            activeTab: 'users'
        })
```

So the html is in `dist/users/__.html` or appropriate, with `app.js` residing under `dist/`

Updating these files, then doing a GAE update does not update the html. I've set a cache expiration of 30s, still not updating.

Is there anything I can do to force all html changes to be uploaded?

JS/CSS files have a version number appended to the end as part of the build process so they work fine, but as far as I can tell that's not possible to do for the html with angular routes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you previously had a longer cache setting for the .html files? In that case they could already be cached on the Google frontend servers. If you look at the response headers in your browser's network inspector you can see if they are indeed cached and perhaps what their age is. You might have to wait till they are evicted from the cache before you can see updates to them again.

In the mean time, try with different filenames and see if that does work.

Another trick you could try is to add a timestamp to the filename.
So instead of requesting `'users.html'` you could request `'users.html?cachebuster=' + +new Date()`

Comment: They initially had no cache, but it turned out the app engine server was serving an older version of the site - it doesn't pick up the version change automatically, so you must set that manually. Additionally, I've added a step to my build process to compile the templates into a template module which angular loads.